# SLF4J version of Logging Event

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I have a Log4J Serializer that uses a Log4J pattern to generate the serialized form.

However, I am migrating to Log4j2, and trying to use SLF4j in my java project except for at runtime when I want to use Log4j2. Is there anyway to refactor the LoggingEvent class in log4j to use a class in slf4j. I have read [here](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/event/LoggingEvent.html) about a SLF4J LoggingEvent, but it is an abstract interface and I do not believe is what I need.

My end goal is to use slf4j for all of my logging, i.e. :

org.slf4j.logger

logger.debug("test");
logger.info("Hello World");

Then in my spring-boot app use log4j2 at **runtime**.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Please provide more detail on how you are currently using the Log4j 1 LogEvent, what you want do, and what is preventing you from doing so.

Comment: Why would you need to refactor LoggingEvent? What does the serialized form look like? (Java Object serialization? Custom binary format? Textual format?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use **log4j-slf4j-impl** lib of log4j2?
When I upgraded (log4j -> log4j2) I had to add to my gradle file these libs:

```
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8'
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.8'
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.8' 
runtime group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.8'
```

However I must admit, I dont use spring-boot, but I hope my hint helps you

Cheers

Comment: It turns out I needed the log4j-slf4j-impl lib as well as jcl and jul to bridge those logs to slf4j. Thanks for your help!